# Flask Application Memory Leak

Tags: python, tensorflow, heroku, memory, memory-leaks

I have a flask application that has a memory leak and I am unable to figure out where I'm going wrong. The application is being used to demonstrate Tensorflow models live through an application. After calling the model to load and predict on an image, the memory increases to 108% on Heroku leading to a R14. Afterwards, the memory never goes back to a healthy level unless the dynos are restarted.

Edit: After further analysis I found that the "load_model(f)" line is causing the leak; though I'm unsure why loading a model from TF would cause this issue.

The following is the code:

```
def read_image(filename):
    t1 = sitk.ReadImage(filename)
    t2 = sitk.GetArrayFromImage(t1)
    X = np.array(t2[(int(len(t2)/2))])
    X = scipy.ndimage.zoom(X, 224/288)
    X = np.stack((X,)*3, axis=-1)

    return X

@app.route("/predict", methods = ['GET','POST'])
def predict():
    f = "models/model"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        file = request.files['file']
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = file.filename
            file_path = os.path.join('static/images', filename)
            file.save(file_path)
            img = read_image(file_path)
            model = load_model(f)
            img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0).astype(np.float32)
            predictions = model.predict(img)
            label_index = int(np.round(predictions[0][0]))
            result = ""
            if label_index == 0:
              result = "case0"
            elif label_index == 1:
              result = "case1"

            return render_template('test.html', result = result, filename = "test.png", css="show")

    return render_template('test.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your model is too big and thats your problem

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue. I've seen similar models in deployment before.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Memory leaks can occur when objects are not properly released or garbage collected. Ensure that you are properly closing files, releasing resources, and using context managers where necessary. Double-check your code to make sure you're not inadvertently holding onto references to objects that should be released.

Comment: I tested the above code with everything except for load_model(f) and model.predict and in that scenario, the memory usage remained constant. I think the issue is in those two lines but I'm unsure how to release the memory that tensorflow is holding.